# Multiple private ispell dictionaries

Tags: ispell

I have an application where I want to use ispell and have it use a dictionary constructed from three inputs:

- The default language dictionary (in my case English, provided by the system).
- A manually curated word list (asking ispell to "insert" a word should add to this).
- A dynamically generated list of works.

Importantly, the last source will be regenerated on a regular basis, adding and **removing** words which may or may not be in either of the other two sources.

- Is there any way to do that will ispell?
- Is there any way to do it with an alternative spell checking that has a similar feature set?

---

I can sort of fake things by generating a per-use dictionary:

```
ispell -p <(cat local.dict dynamic.dict | sort -u) $FILE
```

But this doesn't work once I need to add a new word to `local.dict`: ispell has no way to find the original file and thus clearly can't modify it.

What I'd hoped would work is to be able to pass multiple `-p`

```
ispell -p local.dict -p dynamic.dict $FILE
```

But it seems only the last one is even noticed.

I've even tried exploiting the fact ispell will use a merge of both `$PWD/.ispell_words` and `$HOME/.ispell_words` (which would require overriding `$HOME`). That actually works for the most part, but it seems that when adding new words, ispell write out the **merged** dictionary with the result that it copies everything from the current dynamic dictionary to the permanent static one.

---

At this point I'm starting to consider things like merging the English dictionary and the custom one into a temp file and passing that via `-d`. But that sort of thing seems to be an invitation for endless issues, like how to reliably find the dictionary in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

`hunspell` (if you can install it, there's no information about your system) accepts multiple dictionaries with the `-d` flag. Check the manpage for information on the dictionary formats and the specification of the personal dictionary (`-p`).

```
 -d dict,dict2,...
     Set dictionaries by their base names with or without paths. Example of the syntax:
     -d en_US,en_geo,en_med,de_DE,de_med
```

You can find more information in the [man page](https://helpmanual.io/man1/hunspell/).

Comment: That's worth a look, but when I took a look at it, it seems to have significantly inferior parsing. For example, when given `doesn't`, it complains about not finding a matching `'`? Also it doesn't seem to know about a lot of words that `ispell` already knows of by default.

Comment: Correction: the mismatching `'` was a different issue, but it does try to spell check just the `doesn`.